# How to find an odd number in an array?

Tags: algorithm

In an array, there is exactly one element which repeats odd number of times and rest all other elements repeat even number of the times. Find the element optimally

Comment: @Jared, I disagree. This IS homework.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, rather than merely posting a question verbatim.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Sergey! You'll find you get a lot more quality answers if you show us what progress you've made on the problem so far, and ask a specific question when you encounter a specific problem. Contributors to this site generally feel that a student should do his own homework and seek help when a specific roadblock is encountered.

Comment: Would you like to show what you've researched or tried on your own, or were you just hoping we'd do all of your homework for you?

Comment: I don't know why this was closed, honestly I thought it was a fair question.

Answer (score 8):

xor all the elements together.

Example:

> In [3]: reduce( lambda x,y : x^y, [1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 5] )
>
> Out[3]: 4

Comment: Who said it's a number? Or more precisely, who said that only bitwise equivalence indicates equality?

Comment: @Mark peters: If they are representable as finite binary strings (aka vector spaces over F2), it still works :P

Comment: This is really a language and context dependent answer.  It addresses a very special case that *might* relate to the OP's but very well might not.

Comment: The question *is* limited to "numbers" and there *is* the restriction that only one number is odd so ...

Comment: @Mark Peters:  I don't think you understood my previous remark.  It would work with **any** binary representation, whether it is a raw binary dump of the object, a hash code or a pointer.

Comment: @Mikola: I understood your remark perfectly fine.  There are other definitions of "equals" than bitwise equivalence that occur in many languages, and the xor solution only works for bitwise equivalence.  As an example, consider a type that represents a polynomial.  Two polynomials can be expressed in completely different ways and yet represent the same line.  Pointers would give you instance equality and a hash code could give incorrect results.  I'm not saying this isn't a great solution when it *is* a type where only bitwise equivalence defines a duplicate, I'm just saying it's not general.

Comment: @pst: The question makes no such limitation.  The title says "how to find an odd number" but if you actually read the question you'll see that the "number" in question is the number of *times* a certain element (of unspecified type) is repeated in the array (with an unspecified definition of "repeated").

Comment: @Mark Peters: Ok, fair enough

Comment: @Mikola: Not to say you couldn't take the approach of, "given a domain of objects, assign a unique binary value to every unique instance" and then do your solution on that.  But that gets beyond practical :-)